# Contentful Javascript SDK and NativeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, nativescript, contentful

I am struggling to get the JavaScript Contentful SDK working within my Nativescript application. Sadly, I am new to NativeScript so may be missing something fundamental. Hopefully someone can help :)

The module is installed in my NativeScript project in the usual way:

`npm install contentful`

I then make a simple module (based on an example I found at Github https://github.com/contentful-labs/product-catalogue-web.ts):

```
import {ContentfulClientApi, createClient} from 'contentful';

export class ContentfulService {
      cdaClient: ContentfulClientApi;
      constructor() {

         this.cdaClient = createClient({
             space: 'spaceId',
             accessToken: 'token'
         });
      }
      getContent() {
          this.cdaClient.getContentTypes()
          .then(function(response) { 
            console.log(response.items);
            return response.items;
        })
      }
  }
```

And in a NativeSctipt view model:

```
import { ContentfulService } from "../shared/cms";

let cms = new ContentfulService();
cms.getContent();
```

... but nothing happens. No errors or debug output, however the Native Script view model doesn't do anything at all - code doesn't execute. If I remove the `createClient()` code from the constructor and I just put a console.log in `getContent()` then the console.log works as expected when I call getContent() from the view model

If I try this outside of NativeScript e.g. using the boiler plate node project from the Contentful dashboard, that works as expected.

The reason I want to use the SDK is I need to support offline content via the sync, and the SDK seems to make this easy (if I could get it working!).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the Contentful SDK isn't compatible with Native Script, so for now I'm going to swap to using React Native. You can use fetch with the Contentful REST API but I was after some of the extra SDK functionality like offline caching.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have specific experience with NativeScript, but as it just uses TypeScript / JavaScript under the hood:

`getContent` has to return the Promise the Contentful client gives back:

```
return this.cdaClient.getContentTypes()
.then(...)
```

What might be happening here is, that the returned Promise rejects, but as it isn't used somewhere else and has no `catch` block assigned, it is silently swallowed.

```
return this.cdaClient.getContentTypes()
.then(...)
.catch(function (error) {
  console.error(error)
})
```

Comment: Thanks - I think you're definitely right about that - however it hasn't fixed it. I have been experimenting some more and I think it might be that the Contentful SDK uses npm modules which might not work out of the box with NativeScript ( see https://www.nativescript.org/blog/how-to-use-any-npm-module-with-nativescript ).

Comment: Weird that it silently swallows when whole modules are not available. Did it work out with using `nativescript-nodeify`?

Comment: It didn’t fix it but it did generate a crash when initiating the module, window is undefined. Looks like the Contentful sdk detects a Native script app as a browser which of course it isn’t. I think I’ll have to swap to using React Native ....